# Android app unable to delete answers

Tags: feature-request, android-app

There is no way to delete an answer that you have posted. I find it all too easy to accidentally post an answer instead of a comment, (maybe some better posting differentiation is needed?) and it's not possible to delete the mistakenly created answer ater copying the content to a comment.

On the web I don't need to "vote" to delete my own answers. This has nothing to do with allowing voting on deletion, but the direct (and immediate) deletion of my own answers to questions which doesn't require any voting of any form at all. I just press "delete" and it's deleted.

Comment: I don't want to vote to delete others' posts - I want to delete my own answers in the same way that I can from the website.

Comment: Read the comments on that question. When you click on "delete" on your post, it's still a vote to delete. Yours just happens to be binding.